# Sqlite does not accept create table

Tags: sql, sqlite, auto-increment

I am trying to create a table on sqlite3 on terminal. The command looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id int not null auto_increment primary key ,
col2 varchar(25) not null ,
col2 varchar(40) not null ,
col3 varchar(20) not null ,
col4 float not null
) engine = MYISAM ;
```

I constantly get `Error: near "auto_incement": syntax error` but I can't find it. Any suggestions to fix it would be really helpful.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.
The keyword should be `AUTOINCREMENT` and not `AUTO_INCREMENT` and it can only be used if you define the column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.
But then again you don't really need `AUTOINCREMENT` in the definition:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

By defining the column as `integer primary key` it will also be auto increment.
If you use the keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` in the definition:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

then the values in the column `id` will never be reused (so after a deletion of a row there will be gaps in the ids).
Of course there is no need for `NOT NULL` since you define a primary key and SQLite does not support the definition of a storage engine (like MySql does).
So change your statement to this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id integer primary key ,
  col1 varchar(25) not null ,
  col2 varchar(40) not null ,
  col3 varchar(20) not null ,
  col4 float not null
);
```